# SimpleIoc Not Registering VM with key

Tags: c#, mvvm-light, silverlight-5.0

Toolkit binary version: 4.0.30319

I have been unsuccessful in registering a viewmodel with a key using SimpleIoc with the SL5 binaries.  The only time I've gotten it to work is when I used the SL4 binaries from the [Mix 11 navigation sample](http://blog.galasoft.ch/archive/2011/04/13/deep-dive-mvvm-samples-mix11-deepdivemvvm.aspx) in a SL4 project.

Here is the code to register my VM with SimpleIoc:

```
if (!SimpleIoc.Default.Contains<DeviceListDetailViewModel>(commandParam))
{
     SimpleIoc.Default.Register(
         () => new DeviceListDetailViewModel(this.Repository, this.NavService) { NavParameter = commandParam }, commandParam);
}
```

And here is where I check for the instance in my view and get "Item not Found":

```
if (DataContext == null)
{
     var url = e.Uri.ToString();
     NavParam = url.Substring(url.IndexOf("?") + 1);

     if (!SimpleIoc.Default.Contains<DeviceListDetailViewModel>(NavParam))
     {
           MessageBox.Show("Item not found");
           return;
     }

     var vm = SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance<DeviceListDetailViewModel>(NavParam);
     DataContext = vm;
 }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Registering a view model does not create an instance unless you pass in true for createInstanceImmediately. So, at the point where you are calling Contains, no instance has been created.

You can see that in the [documentation](http://www.mvvmlight.net/help/WP8/html/d1b36f20-c8b2-9169-0a8b-0322e80a1287.htm%22documentation%22)